# AngularJS - Displaying a grid with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to draw a grid of canvas element. Each element of the grid has a color attribute and an id. This is how I create the two-dimensions array :

```
$scope.hexGrid = new Array();
for (var i = 0 ; i < GRIDSIZE ; i++) {
    $scope.hexGrid[i] = new Array();
}

for (var i = 0 ; i < GRIDSIZE ; i++) {
    for (var j = 0 ; j < GRIDSIZE ; j++) {
        var hex = {color: "green", id: i * GRIDSIZE + j};
        $scope.hexGrid[i].push(hex);
    }
}
```

Now here's my question. How would I display a grid using ng-repeat and this two-dimensions array? Should I nest 2 ng-repeat (one for the columns, one for the rows)?

```
<span ng-repeat="hex in hexGrid[1] track by hex.id">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas> 
</span>
```

The first ng-repeat works well for a fixed row, but how should I make the second ng-repeat?

(and finally, is this even a good method?)

Comment: According to Angularjs, It's usually not a good practice to have nested ng-repeats.

Comment: @OzgurGUL please cite source of that *"According to Angularjs"* statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should nest ng-repeats. Also, I'd suggest you to use class="myCanvas" instead of id for obvious html tagging reasons.

```
<span ng-repeat="arr in hexGrid">
    <span ng-repeat="hex in arr track by hex.id">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make it completely dynamic.

Code is attached below:

### Controller:

```
$scope.hexGrid = [];
$scope.hexGrid[0] = [{name:'Test'},{name: 'Test1'}];
$scope.hexGrid[1] = [{name: 'Xyz'}, {name: 'Xyz1'}];
```

### Html:

```
<div ng-repeat="outer in hexGrid">
   <div ng-repeat="inner in outer">
     {{inner.name}}
   </div>
</div>
```